# Navigation Drawer - Web Application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, web-applications, navigation-drawer

Could someone tell me how I would about implementing a Navigation Drawer like the one seen in the below URL.

https://jhipster.github.io/

It's exactly what I am looking for for my current project, but unfortunately I have no been successful in implementing/finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/) is a great library which integrates React and provides the [Navigation Drawer Component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) that you need.

Comment: you can override the default theme.

Comment: But is it now limited to very basic, flat colours? 
Apologies, I haven;t had a lot of exposure to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are there no actual React UI components like Drawers , dropdowns
written in React only? No jquery. I Would have thought React would be better at this rather than jquery !

Comment: there are, but none in the style I want. (icons showing before hovering over)